# Manually extract date from Rails date model object helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working with a Rails (v5.1) form that uses [model object date helpers](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#using-date-and-time-form-helpers-model-object-helpers) which submits dates selected via three dropdowns (d/m/y) as parameters like

```
{..."next_inspection_date(3i)"=>"14", "next_inspection_date(2i)"=>"8", "next_inspection_date(1i)"=>"2019"...}
```

By Rails magic, `MyModel.new(params)` knows what to do with this, but I have some extra logic I'd like to apply when a form is submitted. I could write something like

```
TimeWithZone.parse("#{params[:next_inspection_date(1i)]}-#{params[:next_inspection_date(2i)]}-#{params[:next_inspection_date(3i)]}")
```

to extract a date but this will get repetitive quickly with several dates. To DRY it up manually will likely produce something pretty terse to read and introduce a lot of logic that will really distract from what I'm trying to do. I was wondering if Rails has a built-in helper, so that I could write something like

```
MyModel.next_inspection_date = useful_date_helper(params, :next_inspection_date)
```

The Rails guides merely state that methods like `update` or `new` understand what to do with these params.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Do you intend to make changes before saving it in the model?

Comment: If yes, why not just do in create/update action of your controller (before saving): `params[:next_inspection_date] = your_date`. If you are not clear what I mean, just share code of the action and I will add the answer with changes you need to make.

Comment: TL;DR: I want to update @MyModelInstance in memory and render a view without saving it.

Longer version: I've added a button to my form that queries an external service that can populate some of this form for a user. The user clicks 'lookup', the form is submitted; I perform the API query server side, and re-render the form reflecting both the API results but also any changes the user has made before clicking 'lookup'.

Comment: What you can do is that extract the value of the param like `next = params[:next_inspection_date]` and send it back with response of your API request separately?

Comment: So because of the rails form helpers, `params[:next_inspection_date]` isn't defined- what is defined instead is `params[:next_inspection_date(1i)`, `params[:next_inspection_date(2i)`, etc. Extracting it is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These attributes are known as multi-parameter attributes and the the functionality is unfortunately buried deep inside of [ActiveRecord::AttributeAssignment](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4f66945cd038bda638fc6729e0d54663d0dfbf22/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb#L43). But you can just use ActiveRecord's implementation without saving the record:

```
next_inspection_date = MyModel.new(params.permit(:next_inspection_date)).next_inspection_date
```

You could also replicate it which is really more interesting if you are building something like query objects or virtual models:

```
module MultiparamExtractor
  # Extracts 'i' from foo(3i)
  REGEXP = /\w*\(\d*(?<type>[a-z])\)/.freeze

  # Extracts an array of cast values from a hash containing one multi-parameter attribute
  # @param hash [Hash|ActionController::Parameters]
  # @return [Array]
  def self.call(multi_params)
    # coerce input into a hash
    if multi_params.respond_to?(:permit)
      multi_params.dup.permit!.to_h  # .dup prevents mutating the arguments
    else
      multi_params
    end.sort # sorts by key <=> other key and returns an array
       .map do |(key,value)|
         typecast(value, REGEXP.match(key)[:type])
       end
  end

  private
  # @todo handle casting more types
  def self.typecast(value, type)
    case type
    when 'i'
      value.to_i
    else
      value
    end
  end
end
```

```
# Just for the sake of the example
params = ActionController::Parameters.new("next_inspection_date(3i)"=>"14", "next_inspection_date(2i)"=>"8", "next_inspection_date(1i)"=>"2019", "foo" => "bar")
date = Date.new(*MultiparamExtractor.call(params.permit(:next_inspection_date))).in_time_zone
# Wed, 14 Aug 2019 00:00:00 UTC +00:00
```